# LED Viewing angle

Tags: led

I would like to know more about viewing angle of LED.

Take an example of a LED outline and its viewing angle.

LED outline dimensions as below :
[image]

LED Viewing angle :
[image]

[image]

I would like know where centre origin resembles on actual LED. Is it Point A or Point B. ( Centre origin, Point A and Point B shown in above pic in red )

Thank you.

New  Image - [image]

Comment: It will be neither A nor B. The center is practically never a point, so the center is hypothetical. It will depend on the silicon surface area as well as the lens focal length and should theoretically fall behind the silicon. I very much doubt the datasheet will specify these. Someone requiring this level of accuracy will probably also have the competence to calculate it. Also, the light falloff curves will be very weird/curved extremely close to the LED, which the datasheet does not show.

Comment: @Indraneel, I agree with you, datasheet does not show this.

Comment: Probably far nearer A than B. The degree of accuracy expected from a moulded epoxy lens and supplied graph are such that you probably cannot rely on them to be highly accurate. What is your application that causes this to be important?

Comment: While that's a 60 degree half angle, and output is down 20% at 70 degrees and up about 30% at 50 degrees, the total radiant energy output variation between 50, 60 or 70 degrees is much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Zero degrees is the axis joining point A and B, outside the lens. The centre origin is measured from this axis. It's not a point but a line

Comment: so zero  degree line co-insides with point A and Point B.

Comment: Why I have this question in my mind, I came across one LED (MPN- NSPW570DS) which have lighting element at point A rather than normal LED which have at point B. I have updated image of the same.

Comment: @Micro That beam will spread out more. To have maximum benefit of the lens, the silicon needs to be at the focal point of the lens. Shifting the silicon away from that can and is used to alter the beam angle.

Comment: @Indraneel and/or is due to manufacturing non-tolerances :-)

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are spatially incoherent light sources, meaning the rays do not originate from a point, but rather from an area. Therefore what you measure will depend on how far away away you are looking. Light gains coherence over distance, so from far back the source will become pointlike and appear to be roughly in the center. From close up, the area of the emitter will be apparent and you will see an image of the diode area if you try to focus the light.

This makes optical design hard, so many vendors will provide ray data that can be used to numerically solve for what the output of an LED will look like as a function of distance. For example, Samsung lists theirs along side the datasheet:

https://www.samsung.com/led/lighting/mid-power-leds/3030-leds/lm301b/

Unfortunately, while simulation with the ray data isn't too hard, the software to use the ray files tends to be quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is where the die **appears** to be (because of refraction closer to the surface than it really is) in the photo of the LED (the yellow area in your last picture), i.e. neither at A nor at B, but quite close to A.

Note that this makes it (a little bit) depending on then positon of the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be near or at the center of radius of the curvature (typically well in front of where the die is located), but if you look at the literature on LED goniophotometry (for example, [this](https://www.academia.edu/19317747/LED_goniometry_the_requirements_study)) there does not seem to be a strong consensus.

[image]

[This](http://www.instrumentsystems.com/fileadmin/editors/downloads/Products/LEDGON100_e.pdf) datasheet for a professional goniophotometer shows the LED being rotated about the tip of the lens.

[image]

These are supposed to be far-field measurements, but the difference in the center of rotation would certainly have some effect on the measurements.